# Android ListView - filter by multi select dropdown

Tags: android, filtering

I have ListView with product lists. Each product has different attribute values like size, price, color etc. There are drop downs with range of values to filter the product listing based on the range selected in eact attribute items. meaning prodcuts : red and blue, price between 5000 and 10000, size between 10 to 20, 20 to 30. I have used BaseAdapter to attach the data to listview.

Comment: so you will have sort main list and call notifydatasetchanged method

Comment: If any issue post your code

Comment: Thanks pawan. I am just in a design phase. not yet started the code. I am thinking of use filterable in the adapter. But wondering how do send the multiple criteria and same criteria may have multiple values???